# Perl requires explicit package name but already defined in scope (works without strict)

Tags: perl, scope

I am having the issue that even though I have declared my variable in a higher scope, when I go to use it I'm told that it requires explicit package name. The code is as follows:

```
my $stats = {
    privileges => (),
    missing_users => ()
};

LINE:
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp($line);
    next if $line eq "";

    my $regex = "";
    my $type = "";

    while (($type, $regex) = each(%$entry_regex))
    {
        if ($line =~ /$regex/) {
            if ($type eq "EXCEPTION_PRIVS")
44:         {
45:             push(@{$stats{privileges}}, $1);
46:             next LINE;
            }
```

The error I get is:

> Global symbol "%stats" requires explicit package name at Import
>   Routine Log Pars er.pl line 45.

I do not get this error, and the script runs as desired, when `use strict;` is removed.

I thought that since I have declared it in a 'higher' scope that it should be accessible to the code within the loop. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What error and what variable?

Comment: Also, you've misspelled "privileges", which may cause problems down the road.

Comment: `foreach my $line (<$fh>)` is a wasteful version of `while (my $line = <$fh>)`

Comment: Apologies for that everyone, I've added the error message and line reference. In my rush I forgot that last night. I've updated the code in the question too to reflect changes made after suggestions here.

Comment: Ah, there was two errors! I didn't see the second one. Giving the error message helps! (Better yet, also give runable code so the fixes can be tested.)

Comment: I think some confusion comes from my understanding of when to use %var = () or $var = {} and hence what is actually stored in either object. But your answers have helped clear that up for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not getting a `strict vars` error; you're getting a `strict refs` error. **[Update**: Actually, you have both! LHMathies has pointed out the `strict vars` error, so I won't mention it again.**]**

There's no scoping issue. The immediate error is that you treat the value of `$stats->{priveleges}` (a string) as an array reference.

```
my $stats = {
    priveleges    => (),
    missing_users => (),
};
```

is the same as

```
my $stats = { 'priveleges', 'missing_users' };
```

meaning the resulting hash will have one element whose key is `priveleges` (misspelled) and whose value is `missing_users`.

To create an anonymous array, use `[]`.

```
my $stats = {
    priveleges    => [],
    missing_users => [],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `push` statement is wrong here

```
push(@{$stats{priveleges}}, $1);
```

I think you want to declare `my $stats` like so:

```
my $stats = {
    foo => [],
    bar => [],
}
```

Then you can push onto this array ref:

```
push @{ $stat->{foo} }, $1;
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `push` statement; the array reference will be autovivified.

Comment: @friedo, No, it won't. chrsblck's explanation wasn't the best, but he's right.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There is a string where I thought an `undef` would be.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, `$stats{privileges}` is trying to look in a hash called `%stats`, but you have a hash reference in `$stats`. Try this as line 45:

```
push(@{$stats->{privileges}}, $1);
```

Now that you fixed all the other problems, I think it should work.

Comment: Actually chrsblck showed that too, but you didn't apply that part of the fix.